# log4j2 does not seem to be following my log rolling policies

Tags: jboss, log4j2

We are using log4j2 to handle our application logs, and the application is running under JBoss EAP 7.1.

In my log4j2.xml file, I am trying to keep a maximum of 5 log files of 10MB each, but there is something strange going on because I am ending up with 5 **or more** log files **per day** (depending on the appender). I don't know how/why the date is being added to my file names for most of my logs nor why I have more than 5 logs (per day) in some instances.

Here is part of my log4j2.xml:

```
<RollingFile name="springAppender" fileName="/opt/jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/log/spring.log"
             filePattern="/opt/jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/log/spring-%i.log">
  <PatternLayout> <pattern>%d${ISO8601} [%t] [%X{sessionId}] [%X{orgName}] %-9p %c - %enc{%m}%n</pattern></PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
  </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
</RollingFile>
<RollingFile name="SqlAppender" fileName="/opt/jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/log/sql.log"
             filePattern="/opt/jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/log/sql-%i.log">
  <PatternLayout> <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%t] [%X{sessionId}] [%X{orgName}] %-9p %c - %enc{%m}%n</pattern></PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
  </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5"/>
</RollingFile>
```

And here is an excerpt of my log directory listing:

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485857 May 30 05:26 spring-05-30-2019-1.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485924 May 30 05:34 spring-05-30-2019-2.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485861 May 30 05:40 spring-05-30-2019-3.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485796 May 30 05:49 spring-05-30-2019-4.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485946 May 30 05:56 spring-05-30-2019-5.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485950 May 30 07:43 spring-05-30-2019-6.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485808 May 30 13:13 spring-05-30-2019-7.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss    2302827 Jun 25 17:51 spring.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485766 Jun 25 04:51 sql-1.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485896 Jun 25 04:52 sql-2.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485990 Jun 25 04:54 sql-3.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485874 Jun 25 04:56 sql-4.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss   10485967 Jun 25 04:58 sql-5.log`

`-rw-r--r--. 1 jboss jboss    5782246 Jun 25 14:55 sql.log`

As far as I can see, the `SqlAppender` and the `springAppender` are structurally the same. Yet my sql.log rolls as desired, while spring.log both includes the date in the rolled file name as well as preserves more than the max 5 files. This is slowly filling my hard drive.

I have grepped within my JBoss directory looking for patterns like `"\-yyyy\-"` that might tip me off to another place that might be controlling how logs roll to no avail.

We run in standalone mode, and there is a `periodic-rotating-file-handler` in our standalone.xml, but that controls server.log. There is also a logging.properties file that I believe controls logging until the application fully starts and hands off the logging to log4j2, but I don't see anything in there that seems to contain a pattern that would insert a date into my file names.

How do I stop this behavior?

Comment: The fist thing I would do is change the pattern of the PatternLayout to see if the resulting logs are truly generated by log4j.

Comment: Changing the pattern also tells you if the config file you think you're using is really the one being used by log4j2.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24566672/12224743) might help your query. I hope

Comment: @D.B. The logs seem to be generated by log4j but something else is controlling the rolling.

Comment: @Umeshwaran, unfortunately that answer did not address the problem I am experiencing.